# Dynamically pushing information to Estimote Beacons?

Tags: estimote

I'm thinking of an interface that allows changing what the beacon displays, on the fly. For instance, a web interface that lets me choose between various items as well as a beacon -- and any mobile devices in proximity to that beacon display the item I chose.

Similarly, if I change the item on the web interface, the beacon should update. Looking at the API docs, I don't think this sort of thing would be possible?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.estimote.com/managing-beacons/bulk-updater/

https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/200868188-How-to-modify-iBeacon-s-UUID-Major-and-Minor-values-

Try updating the uids and linking dynamically to custom named content that you want to push. Even a slight firmware update might do the trick.